# Getting rid of @ and Creating Home and Away Teams

Tags: r

I am trying to make a home and away column for this team, in a data table that looks like

```
   X2021        Angels
1    1-Apr     White Sox
2    2-Apr     White Sox
3    3-Apr     White Sox
4    4-Apr     White Sox
5    5-Apr        Astros
6    6-Apr        Astros
7    7-Apr              
8    8-Apr    @Blue Jays
9    9-Apr    @Blue Jays
```

Every time the Angels are playing. If the team contains an @ it is away, no @ it is home, and empty there is no game. I want a column of Home Team and Away Team, where if it is away (containing @) the Angels are home and the other team is away without the @. What would look like

```
  X2021        Angels     Home_Team   Away_Team
1    1-Apr     White Sox  Angels      White Sox
2    2-Apr     White Sox  Angels      White Sox
3    3-Apr     White Sox  Angels      White Sox
4    4-Apr     White Sox  Angels      White Sox
5    5-Apr        Astros  Angels      Astros
6    6-Apr        Astros  Angels      Astros
7    7-Apr                      
8    8-Apr    @Blue Jays  Blue Jays   Angels
9    9-Apr    @Blue Jays  Blue Jays   Angels
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? I think `ifelse(grepl("@", Angels), .., ..)` (twice) would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JacksonDels,

Assuming your data is in an spreadsheet, here's some code that will do what you're trying to do.

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Read in data table
df <- readxl::read_xlsx("angels.xlsx")

# Create two new columns for "Home" and "Away" teams
df <- df %>% 
  mutate("Home_Team" = if_else(str_detect(string = Angels, pattern = "@"), str_remove(string = Angels, pattern = "@"), "Angels")) %>%
  mutate("Away_Team" = if_else(str_detect(string = Angels, pattern = "@"), "Angels" ,str_remove(string = Angels, pattern = "@")))
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Using base R :

```
transform(df, Home_Team = ifelse(startsWith(Angels, '@') | Angels == '', 
                                 sub('@', '', Angels, fixed = TRUE), 'Angels'), 
              Away_Team = ifelse(startsWith(Angels, '@'), 'Angels', Angels)) 

#  X2021    Angels Home_Team Away_Team
#1 1-Apr  WhiteSox    Angels  WhiteSox
#2 2-Apr  WhiteSox    Angels  WhiteSox
#3 3-Apr  WhiteSox    Angels  WhiteSox
#4 4-Apr  WhiteSox    Angels  WhiteSox
#5 5-Apr    Astros    Angels    Astros
#6 6-Apr    Astros    Angels    Astros
#7 7-Apr                              
#8 8-Apr @BlueJays  BlueJays    Angels
#9 9-Apr @BlueJays  BlueJays    Angels
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(X2021 = c("1-Apr", "2-Apr", "3-Apr", "4-Apr", 
"5-Apr", "6-Apr", "7-Apr", "8-Apr", "9-Apr"), Angels = c("WhiteSox", 
"WhiteSox", "WhiteSox", "WhiteSox", "Astros", "Astros", "", "@BlueJays", 
"@BlueJays")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```